# Get the PDF`s file in print() dialog with javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a button for print my website:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print Page</a>
```

I observe that the print dialog with javascript generate a PDF file:
[image]

**How to get this PDF directly with javascript?**

I want make two buttons, the first is to print(), the second generate the PDF:
[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Funny Frontend,
    Were you able to get the PDF in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without any library. As I know, there is no option to force the pdf print. But, using http://parall.ax/products/jspdf, or another lib that does the same things, you would be able to generate the pdf you want.

Comment: I try this library, but generate a PDF with only text, without css styles.